# Background task management in an asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `ASP.NET` application that I have built for our retail store. One feature for this system is to send an existing order to our POS system in order to expedite the creation of a receipt for a customer. This process encompasses several methods currently running synchronously, of which only a few are important to the process of creating the receipt and getting the customer quickly processed. The remaining methods are cleanup and housekeeping needed by the POS and the internal app and these methods take the most time.

Currently, the button press to start this process stalls the app for approx 20 seconds while all this work is being done.

```
protected void btnSendReceipt_Click(...)
{
     Method1(); // < 1 sec
     Method2(); // < 1 sec
     Method3(); // < 1 sec
     Method4(); // 10+ sec
     Method5(); // 10+ sec

     Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); 
}
```

`Method1`, `Method2`, and `Method3` are required in order for the web app to have everything it needs but `Method4` and `Method5` take all the time. I have researched `async` `await` but because I am not waiting for any `return` from these methods I'm not sure if this is really what I want to do. Further research indicates that starting threads is expensive and wasteful. So my question is, what is what I am trying to archive called, and which direction should I focus my learning efforts to achieve this efficiently and with proper design? (Note that exceptions are handled internally in `Method4` and `Method5` and any issues arising from their execution are external to the web app and are handled separately. Also, these methods make calls to external tools that I cannot optimize so the 10+ second run time is not within my control.)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can Method4 and Method5 be run in parallel?

Comment: @Eugene YES -- Method4 and Method5 could run in parallel, absolutely.

Comment: please glance at Invoke method in System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel class: [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd992634.aspx)

Comment: If you don't need a return from methods 4 & 5, you can use Task.Run(()=>Method4()); Task.Run(()=>Method5())); to avoid having to wait for responses from them and just redirect after starting the tasks. Tasks use less overhead than Threads.

Comment: As an aside, if you're a self-taugh dev and want to move from junior to senior, I suggest reading CLR via C# 4th edition.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene and @Kell. Which is most appropriate here? I am thinking `Task.Run`? CLR C# 4ed on its way from Amazon, thank you for the suggestion @Kell.

Comment: @Kell your first comment is an actual answer... I think It would be appropriate to answer the OP

Comment: Added as as answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a return from methods 4 & 5, you can use

```
Task.Run(()=>Method4()); 
Task.Run(()=>Method5()));
```

to avoid having to wait for responses from them and just redirect after starting the tasks. Tasks use less overhead than Threads

Comment: This cut the time down to less than a second, thanks much it was exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

This will run all methods in parallel:

```
 protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>
        {
            Method1(),
            Method2(),
            Method3(),
            Method4(),
            Method5()
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task Method1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    public async Task Method2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    public async Task Method3()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    public async Task Method4()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }

    public async Task Method5()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
```

You may not care about the result from Method 4/5 but do you want the task to be fire and forget? This is something to consider as exceptions may occur. Awaiting the response will give you the opportunity to catch those exceptions and take action accordingly.